# How to use image data from PHImageManager

Tags: ios, core-image, photosframework

I need to process and store image data from PHImageManager as efficiently as possible.

To that end, I need to get a hold of each image in the iOS photo album, such that I can read it through a CIImage object, so I can apply filters and extract descriptors for a CBIR database on a separate thread.

Using `[PHAsset requestContentEditingInput]` to open the image file by URL isn't an option.  It technically works to open the image file and read it, but I've had bad luck with it as it forces callbacks into the main queue and seems to be dependent on keeping the calls in the main queue.  It will crash the app after processing several images on a background queue and I'm fairly sure the API is made only for editing sessions that would occur in the main queue.

PHImageManager offers an API `requestImageDataForAsset` that can be invoked synchronously on a background thread.  This seems more suitable for an image processing app that needs to process images without acting as an interactive editing tool, which is my exact use case.  I also need metadata, specifically the orientation of the image, which this API returns as well.

The trouble is that I can't find a scrap of information that actually discusses this API.  It says that it will return an NSData, but that doesn't tell me that it will be the bitmap RBG data, JPEG data, and other information that is useful.

I want to create a CIImage with this data, but the API doesn't give me pixel format, color space, or anything else.  I can probably assume RGB and 3 bytes per pixel.  But this could probably be wrong.

Has anyone used this API and can explain its behavior?  Apple's 2014 WWDC videos don't even really discuss it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some tinkering and experimenting, the NSData object that is returned can be used to create a CIImage object using `+[CIImage imageWithData:]`.

According to the method's documentation, the data must be an image stream format like JPEG or TIFF, so it would make sense that the stream is one of them.

Additionally, there does seem to be a bug in iOS 9 that causes `+[CIImage imageWithContentsOfURL:]` to crash if the image at URL is corrupt or can't be used to create an image.

The crash can be avoided by checking whether `+[CIImage imageWithData:]` returns nil, suggesting that the image data at URL cannot be used to generate a CIImage.